# Symfony 5.4 trouble setting up drenso/symfony-oidc-bundle

Tags: symfony, openid-connect

Im trying to set up an open id connection with this bundle https://github.com/Drenso/symfony-oidc. Did the first step of configuration

```
drenso_oidc:
    #default_client: default # The default client, will be aliased to OidcClientInterface
    clients:
        default: # The client name, each client will be aliased to its name (for example, $defaultOidcClient)
            # Required OIDC client configuration
            well_known_url: '%env(OIDC_WELL_KNOWN_URL)%'
            client_id: '%env(OIDC_CLIENT_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET)%'

            # Extra configuration options
            #redirect_route: '/login_check'
            #custom_client_headers: []

        # Add any extra client
        #link: # Will be accessible using $linkOidcClient
            #well_known_url: '%env(LINK_WELL_KNOWN_URL)%'
            #client_id: '%env(LINK_CLIENT_ID)%'
            #client_secret: '%env(LINK_CLIENT_SECRET)%'
```

Variables are also set in my .env.

when i enable oidc in my security.yml, this happen :
[image]
here's my security.yml :

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\BackUser: auto
        App\Entity\FrontUser: auto

    providers:
        users:
            chain:
                providers: [back_users, front_users]
        back_users:
            entity: { class: App\Entity\BackUser, property: username }
        front_users:
            entity: { class: App\Entity\FrontUser, property: email }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_REDACTOR, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ROLE_REDACTOR:    ROLE_READER
        ROLE_READER:      ROLE_USER

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        back:
            context: global_context
            pattern: ^/back
            #anonymous: ~
            user_checker: App\Security\Checker\UserChecker
            provider: back_users
            switch_user:
              provider: users
              role: CAN_SWITCH_USER
            form_login:
                provider: users
                check_path: back_security_login
                login_path: back_security_login
                #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                enable_csrf: true
                default_target_path: back_static_index
                success_handler: App\Security\Handler\LoginSuccessHandler
                failure_handler: App\Security\Handler\LoginFailureHandler
            logout:
                path: back_security_logout
                target: back_security_login
                handlers:
                  - App\Security\Handler\LogoutHandler
        front:
            context: global_context
            pattern: ^/
            oidc: ~
            #anonymous: ~
            user_checker: App\Security\Checker\UserChecker
            provider: front_users
            switch_user:
              provider: users
              role: CAN_SWITCH_USER
#            form_login:
#                provider: users
#                check_path: front_index
#                login_path: front_index
#                #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
#                enable_csrf: true
#                default_target_path: front_index
#                success_handler: App\Security\Handler\LoginSuccessHandler
            logout:
                path: front_security_logout
                target: front_index
                handlers:
                    - App\Security\Handler\LogoutHandler
```

I just cant figure out why this happen. If someone has a clue or has already used this package and may know what i'm doing wrong?

wishing y'all a good day

Answer (score 0):

Your UserProvider (in your example App\Entity\FrontUser) must implements OidcUserProviderInterface

From the documentation:
https://github.com/Drenso/symfony-oidc#user-provider

Comment: Do you have an example of `ensureUserExists()` and `loadOidcUser()` ?